# Android: Edit a view similar to the edit contacts view

Tags: android

I am trying to create an App that has a similar layout as the view you get when you edit a contact. The main functionality I need is the ability to click a "+" or "-" button in the row and add/remove another row where the user can input another line of data.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

I have looked into the expandable lists but I am not sure if this is what I should be using or if it is just a list with a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into ListView and ListActivity. there are all kinds of demos out there. once you have a handle on how to make custom list item layouts, you can simply include that button in the item's layout and define it's behavior to do whatever you want.

Let me know if that was helpful